# verbatimTextOutput width based on px

Tags: r, shiny

Is there any way to adjust the `verbatimTextOutput` width based on `px`?
So far, I found that something like

```
fluidRow(column(width = 2,verbatimTextOutput("placeholder", placeholder = TRUE)))
```

change the width of `verbatimTextOutput` based on a selected number of columns. How should I change it to have the width based on `px`? For example, in want to have `width = 280px`.

FYI, I use the renderText to show the result.

Apperiacite!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply `style` as:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  div(style="width:500px;",fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("placeholder", placeholder = TRUE)))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$placeholder <- renderText({"Testing Size by px"})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit: adding padding:**

You can use `padding` or `padding-left` or `padding-top` etc to add the space between the widgets:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  div(style="width:500px;padding-left:100px;",fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("placeholder", placeholder = TRUE)))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$placeholder <- renderText({"Testing Size by px"})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Great. Thanks, @Pork Chop. Just for the sake of curiosity, If you run the code, you see that the verbatimTextOutput sticks to the left side of the window. Is there any way to put some distance (based on px) between the left side of the window and verbatimTextOutput box?

Comment: Thanks for explanation @Pork Chop.

Comment: @PorkChop hi, I see you're very knowledgeable, I was wondering if you could see a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55927637/r-shiny-textoutput-aligned-with-selectinput-element Thanks