# textOutput aligned with selectInput element

Tags: r, shiny

I'm quite new to Shiny and I'm having a hard time to fix the following apparently simple example.
I have the following code:

```
library(shiny)
u <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Simple Selectable Reactive Function"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      h2("Results"),
      fluidRow(column(2,
                      selectInput("aa", "Choose a function", choices=c("sin","cos","exp"))
                      ),
              column(2,
                     textOutput(outputId = "outputText1") 
                     )


      )

    ))
  )

s <- function(input,output){

  output$outputText1 <- renderText({ 
    paste("Sample text")
  })

}
shinyApp(ui=u,server=s)
```

All I'm trying to do is to have "Sample text" aligned at the same height on the screen as the drop down box ("sin").
Right now, the words "Sample text" are aligned with the element label "Choose a function".
I checked ?textOutput but it doesn't seem to be very useful.
Thank you

Comment: Please do not repeat the tags in your question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to wrap your `textOutput(outputId = "outputText1")` with a `tags$div` and add a top padding.

```
library(shiny)
u <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Simple Selectable Reactive Function"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      h2("Results"),
      fluidRow(column(2,
                      selectInput("aa", "Choose a function", choices=c("sin","cos","exp"))
      ),
      column(2,
             tags$div(textOutput(outputId = "outputText1"), style = "padding-top:30px;") 
      )


      )

    ))
)

s <- function(input,output){

  output$outputText1 <- renderText({ 
    paste("Sample text")
  })

}
shinyApp(ui=u,server=s)
```

**Alternative** use two `fluidRow` to make it more responsive. 
In this case the label of the `selectInput` is set to NULL and e.g. a `h5` element is used instead.

```
library(shiny)
u <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Simple Selectable Reactive Function"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      h2("Results"),
      fluidRow(column(2, h5(tags$b("Choose a function")))),
      fluidRow(column(2, selectInput("aa", label = NULL, choices=c("sin","cos","exp"))),
               column(2,textOutput(outputId = "outputText1")))            

      )

    )
)

s <- function(input,output){

  output$outputText1 <- renderText({ 
    paste("Sample text")
  })

}
shinyApp(ui=u,server=s)
```

Comment: Thank you wati, I just tested your solution but the app layout it looks like identical to mine.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case... But I added an alternative that may work.

Comment: I had to restart my R session. both your R solutions work like a charm. Thank you so much wait, much appreciated your great answer.