# Shiny use more than 12 columns in a single row

Tags: r, shiny

I'm a Shiny newbie, so probably mine is a simple question but can't find anybody else asking something similar here on stackoverflow.com.
I would need to build an app with more than 12 columns.
So my question is, how can I have more than 12 textInput elements on the same row and make their width a little bit tighter?
This is my sample code.

```
library(shiny) 
u <- fluidPage(   
  titlePanel("Simple Selectable Reactive Function"),   
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      h2("Results"),
      fluidRow(column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 1",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 2",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 3",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 4",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 5",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 6",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 7",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 8",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 9",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 10",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 11",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text Inp 12",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text Inp 13",
                                value = "123"))

      )
    )
  )
)

s <- function(input,output){} 
shinyApp(ui=u,server=s)
```

thank you for the help.

Comment: Shiny layout functions are built on top of [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) which is where the 12 column row idea originates. You can have more than 12 column elements in a row, but the elements **will wrap** onto the row below. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679160/bootstrap-3-use-more-than-12-columns-in-a-row) for more info.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to change this default and have tigher columns or use a different code instead of "column"? I've seen a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500357/verbatimtextoutput-width-based-on-px where a person was showing how to use style, but to be honest I don't know how I could apply it in my case.

Comment: I don't know how to accomplish that. The main idea of Bootstrap is viewing device flexibility. Elements are sized relative to the device and re-distributed accordingly so they are easily visible, eg 2-cols in 1-row on a monitor would be 6-cols in 2-rows on an ipad and then 3-cols in 4-rows on mobile

Comment: You don't need to use `fluidRow`s: you can just make the columns manually with `div` and CSS. That'll be a pain in the butt, but it's an option if you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `fluidRow` in a `column`again. 
The last `column` is devided again in two columns.

```
library(shiny) 
u <- fluidPage(   
  titlePanel("Simple Selectable Reactive Function"),   
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      h2("Results"),
      fluidRow(
              column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 1",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 2",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 3",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 4",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 5",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 6",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 7",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 8",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 9",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 10",
                                value = "123")),
               column(1,
                      textInput("input_ID", label = "text 11",
                                value = "123")),

               column(1, fluidRow(column(6,
                                         textInput("input_ID", label = "text 12",
                                                   value = "123")),
                                  column(6,
                                         textInput("input_ID", label = "text 13",
                                                   value = "123"))))

      )
    )
  )
)

s <- function(input,output){} 
shinyApp(ui=u,server=s)
```